# Pulsed laser data sheets: "repetition frequency" in Hertz and "repetition rate" in "pps" (assuming pulse(s) per second) are equivalent concepts?

Tags: laser, photonics

When I read the data sheets for pulsed lasers, some specify "repetition frequency" in Hertz, and others specify "repetition rate" in "pps" (assuming pulse(s) per second). I wanted to ask just to be sure: since a Hertz is equal to one cycle per second, these concepts should be equivalent, right? For example, a "repetition frequency" of 10 Hertz should be the same as a "repetition rate" of 10 pps (pulses per second)? It would be great if people with experience in photonics could give input on this.

Comment: Yes, they’re most likely the same. There isn’t really standard terminology here. 1 MHz = 1 million pulses/second.

Comment: @Gilbert Ok, thanks for the clarification.